# Referring to URLs in RESTful APIs

Tags: php, ruby, api, rest, terminology

Here are a couple of standard URLs of a RESTful API.

- http://api.example.com/user/123
- http://api.example.com/users

The first retrieves a single user, the second - a collection of users (let's say 20).

What is the "[REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)" term to refer to these URLs? Is it correct to refer to them as resources? If the first is a resource, should the second be a resource collection or should it rather be just a resource of type collection?

Comment: To be even more precise: the URL is a locator or identifier. The URL is not a resource, it refers to a resource.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every URI on a RESTful application is a resource, this description is sufficient.

Resources that link to several resources of the same type may be called collections, but there is no official name for that. Every resource, being a collection or not, can have links.

Links between resources are the Hypermedia part of a RESTful system. Recently, a new term came up for this: HATEOAS, Hypermedia As The Engine Of Application State.

It's a common good practice to name collections in plural, so your `/users/` sample seems correct. The user 123 is a child of the *users* collection, so it may be better to put it under `/users/123` in plural as well.

A RESTful, HATEOAS application would respond a list of links on `/users/` pointing to individual resources. Something like:

```
{
    "links": [
        {
            "href" : "/users/123/"
            "title" : "Alexandre Gaigalas"
        },
        {
            "href" : "/users/125/"
            "title" : "John Doe"
        },
    ]
}
```

Or in XML:

```
<link href="/users/123" title="Alexandre Gaigalas">
...
```

Additional information apart from the `links` object in JSON or  tags in XML may be provided.

These links stabilish a RESTful hypermedia relationship between resources. The samples I gave are mostly hierarchical between collections and individuals, but other types of links may be declared:

```
<link href="/users/123/picture.jpg" title="Alexandre Gaigalas avatar" rel="picture">
```

The *collection* terminology was created mostly for abstracting a RESTful implementation in programming languages, so developers can group and manipulate groups of similar resources more easily.

When present, query string parameters identify different resources as well, so `/users/?since=2009` is a different from `/users/`. They're both different resources, although very similar ones.

Fragment identifiers, even though not sent to the server anyway, are considered different resources as well, so `/users/123#bio` is different from `/users/123`.

If possible, a more meaningful pagination is better. Page numbers are hard to handle RESTfully because they change a lot. If there is a frequently updated collection (like a list of StackOverflow questions for example), the page one frequently changes and the user may loose items changing from page 1 to page 2. Most collections can be paginated by date or alphabetically. Incremental page numbers aren't wrong, but there are better mechanisms.

Comment: If the URI contains parameters (i.e. `http://api.example.com/users?limit=5&offset=10`), is it still correct to refer to it as a resource? If it is, what would be the name of that resource? Is it still "users"?

Comment: I'm gonna edit the answer to include considerations about query string parameters!

Comment: Done that =) Hope that helps somehow!

Comment: Hm... Is it then correct to refer to any URL in a RESTful API as resource?

Comment: It is correct to refer to any URL as a resource! RESTful is when that resource follows the REST architecture style, which is based on 5 principles: client-server, stateless, cacheable, layered and uniform.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it is better to use `/users/123` over `/user/123`?

Comment: It's more intuitive. If someone lands in `/users/123/` the guy can easily predict that `/users/` would probably work as well. It's something analogous to folders and users are somehow more familiar with this kind of naming.

Comment: Also, linking in hypermedia is easier. Since links can be relative, if the user hits `/users/` the link can be `href=123`. If the plural/singular doesn't match, the link must be something like `href=/user/123`, more verbose.